# Haskell function-next for enums

Tags: haskell, enums

I have an enum and a function to call next element of the enum.

```
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
next :: Day -> Day
next Mon = Tue
next Tue = Wed
next Wed = Thu
next Thu = Fri
next Fri = Sat
next Sat = Sun
next Sun = Mon
```

I try to use this by calling:

```
> next Mon
```

but the compiler shows an error:

```
<interactive>:35:1:
    No instance for (Show Day) arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show Day)
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: your function is fine, but you're trying to print the result so you should add `deriving (Show) at the end of your Day type declaration`

Comment: `data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving (Show)` should fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because GHCi doesn't know how to show the data type. You can fix this by adding a `deriving Show`:

```
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving Show
```

Answer (score 13):

In addition to implementing `Show`, if you implement `Enum` you can simplify your `next` function by using `succ`:

```
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving (Show, Enum)

next :: Day -> Day
next Sun = Mon
next d = succ d
```

you can make a more general version of `next` with this wrap-around behaviour using `Bounded`:

```
next :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
next e | e == maxBound = minBound
       | otherwise = succ e

data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you try it in `ghci`, it wants to show the result in `String`. But it doesn't know how to convert that to `String`.

This can be fixed by:

```
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving (Show)
```

Or in case you want to manually make up the `String`:

```
instance Show Day where
  show Mon = "Monday"
  show Tue = "Tuesday"
  show Wed = "Wednesday"
  --  and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can simplify `next` be letting Haskell derive [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aEnum) and [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aBounded) instances for you:

```
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
  deriving (Bounded, Enum, Show)

next :: Day -> Day
next Sun = Mon
next x = succ x
```